# How to configure apache2 to execute a script before executing orignal request?

Tags: apache-2.2

The following dilemma exists... One virtual hosts, three directories with three different handlers let's say Mason, PHP, Ruby.

```
example.org/Dir1/ (Mason)
example.org/Dir2/ (PHP)
example.org/Dir3/ (Ruby)
```

Now when I request whatever from `Dir2` or `Dir3` I'd like apache2 to execute a script from `Dir1` first followed by the original request. Is it possible to do it with some magic configuration option?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like the only way to do smth like this is writing input handler, that is a program that Apache can use at various stages of processing HTTP request. More here:

http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-filter.html

Comment: Thanks! This is a good starting point to my investigation.